# remove over space char in textbox while editing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set my database(.mdf)  Firstname to (nchar(30)) and Middlename to nchar(30) same to Lastname and Age to nchar(3) ang sex nchar(6)

now the problem is when i save a new record to my database.. 
example: i save (firstname)="Perdo" (Middlename)="Calungsod" (lastname)="Madrigal"

after I save the record it will consume all 30 character that i set and save 
example 
when i save (Firstname)="Pedro" and when you try to edit the record the you will notice the spacing like this ["pedro                        "] like that so i count all the spacing .. the total is 30 including the "pedro" .. so what i want to happen is to delete the white space

im using (VS2010)ASP.NET C#

here's my code for saving

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (save_B.Text == "SAVE")
        {
            try
            {

                //ID NUMBER GENERATES
                var chars = "0123456789";
                var random = new Random();
                var newGUID = new string(
                    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                              .ToArray());

                // SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["User_DB_Connectionstring"].ConnectionString);

                conn.Open();

                string checkuser = "Select count(*) from User_TBL_DB where Firstname='" + T_firstName.Text + "' and Middlename='" + T_middlename.Text + "' and Lastname='" + T_lastname.Text + "' or ID='" + newGUID + "'";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("User Already Exist");
                }
                else
                {

                    try
                    {
                        string Male = "MALE";
                        string Female = "FEMALE";
                        string insertQuery = "insert into User_TBL_DB (Firstname,Middlename,Lastname,Age,Sex,ID) values (@first,@middle,@last,@age,@sex,@id)";
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);


                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_firstName.Text))
                        {
                            T_firstName.Focus();
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_middlename.Text))
                        {
                            T_middlename.Focus();
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_lastname.Text))
                        {
                            T_lastname.Focus();
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_age.Text))
                        {
                            T_age.Focus();
                        }

                        else if (male_b.Checked)
                        {
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", Male);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", T_firstName.Text);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle", T_middlename.Text);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", T_lastname.Text);
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", T_age.Text);

                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newGUID);
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Response.Write("User Registration Accepted");
                            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");

                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Open();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        else if (female_b.Checked)
                        {
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", Female.Trim());
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", T_firstName.Text.Trim());
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle", T_middlename.Text.Trim());
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", T_lastname.Text.Trim());
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", T_age.Text.Trim());

                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newGUID.Trim());
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Response.Write("User Registration Accepted");
                            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");

                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Open();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("Error Saving Please Try Again");

                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
                    }


                }


                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                Response.Write("Error Again to:" + ec.ToString());
            }
        }

        else if (save_B.Text == "UPDATE")
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string Genderselect;
                if (male_b.Checked)
                {
                    Genderselect = "MALE";
                }
                else
                {
                    Genderselect = "FEMALE";
                }

                string checkuser = "Select count(*) from User_TBL_DB where Firstname='" + T_firstName.Text + "' and Middlename='" + T_middlename.Text + "' and Lastname='" + T_lastname.Text + "' and Sex='"+Genderselect+"' and Age='"+T_age.Text+"' ";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("Nothing Changed");
                }
                else
                {
                    string Male = "MALE";
                    string Female = "FEMALE";
                    //conn.Open();

                    string updateData = "UPDATE [User_TBL_DB] set [Firstname]=@Firstname, [Middlename]=@Middlename,[Lastname]=@Lastname,[Age]=@Age,[Sex]=@Sex where [ID]=@ID";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(updateData.Trim(), conn);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_firstName.Text))
                    {
                        T_firstName.Focus();
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_middlename.Text))
                    {
                        T_middlename.Focus();
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_lastname.Text))
                    {
                        T_lastname.Focus();
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T_age.Text))
                    {
                        T_age.Focus();
                    }

                    else if (male_b.Checked)
                    {
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", Male.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", T_firstName.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", T_middlename.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", T_lastname.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", T_age.Text.Trim());

                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID_label.Text.Trim());
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Response.Write("User Registration Accepted");
                        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");

                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Open();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    else if (female_b.Checked)
                    {
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", Female.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", T_firstName.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", T_middlename.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", T_lastname.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", T_age.Text.Trim());

                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID_label.Text.Trim());

                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Response.Write("User Registration Accepted");
                        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");

                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Open();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("Error Saving Please Try Again");

                    }



                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Response.Write(x.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

I included all the validations.. i use trim too but it's not working or im not using it right hehe thank you for reading this and i hope you have the answer to my question have a nice day

Comment: Use `nvarchar` instead of `nchar`.